# What is the best way to submit work to a dask client from a queue?

Tags: dask

We are using Dask in our team to run all our workflows. We currently run workflows automatically like this:

- We run a query to listen for changes inside specific columns in specific SQL tables
- When tables are detected we import our dask delayed graph and run it

The above is working OK but it requires us to query databases and *listen* for changes. There are other cases in which we just need to tell the scheduler to run a workflow. In this case we'd like to add the task to a queue and have it run from there.

I was thinking to use a simple sql table and then have a loop that checks this table for any new work. Once the new work is available it's submitted to dask.distributed.

However this means we'd have to ping this table every 30 seconds or less and it feels a bit hacky to query a table so often 24/7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is "How do I submit a task to a queue with Dask?" then I'll point you to

- Dask futures https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html
- Coordination primitives: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#coordination-primitives

If your question is "how do I monitor a SQL database?" then this is a bit out of the scope of Dask.  Typically whatever you use to insert into the database would also trigger some event somewhere which would trigger computation.  There are many ways to do this, but getting into that here is probably out of scope.